# Finding groups in Regex - Python

Tags: python, regex

I am not able to understand the output of following code I just wrote. I am trying to extract the complete value of the group in a string value.

```
>> str1 = "CREATE TABLE TABLE1 (NAME VARCHAR, PHONE VARCHAR) as SELECT NAME, PHONE FROM SCHEMA1.ADDRESS"
>> pat1 = re.compile("CREATE TABLE .+ FROM (\w).+")
>> ret= pat1.search(str1)
>> ret.groups()
('S',)
```

I was expecting the value to be `SCHEMA1`. How can I retrieve the entire value ?

Why I am doing this?

I have a file filled with DML statements intended for different schemas. So, I need to create separate files for each schema with DML statement from the file mentioned before.

Comment: You are only capturing a single character. `(\w+)` will capture all the characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You meant to write:

```
pat1 = re.compile("CREATE TABLE .+ FROM (\w+)\..+")
```

`\w` captures only a single character; you want to capture all the characters until the dot. `\.` represents the dot, and `.+` represents the rest of the line (`address`).